# Functional way of programming in Java 1.7

Tags: java, functional-programming

Is it possible to code application in functional programming way without using Java 8 and other 3rd party library?
I mean to ask that if we follow some design patterns can that help us achieve functional programming paradigm in Java 1.7

I am not much experienced with design patterns, i have read about them but not able to figure it out where to apply which pattern.

Comment: To the people closing this as "unclear":  it is very much clear as to what is being asked here.

Comment: Design patterns for Java are generally nothing to do with functional programming.  To be honest, Java is not a functional programming language, even in Java 8.  If you want to use the "functional paradigm" you are better off switching to a genuine FP language.  Certainly the people who have to maintain your "functional in Java 7" code will vote that way.

Comment: What if we create a interface with name Callback which has one method func and instead of passing method we will pass object of class implementing that interface and similarly we can return object of class implementing that interface. And while executing callback we can call object.func().

Comment: You're still passing objects around, and you still require an object to implement the interface.

Comment: That isn't functional programming.  That is (simply) simulating "functions as objects" or C / C++ "function pointers".

Comment: There are functional programming languages, even pure ones, on the JVM. Use one of those, and you will even be inter-operable with Java code more or less easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer:  **no.**

Java is an object-oriented programming language, and while Java 8 and third party libraries break up *some* of the ceremony, at its core you're still dealing with classes.

The functional design patterns you're attempting to apply won't work in this language (or if they do it'd be difficult to maintain and hard to read).  You should consider using OO design patterns instead.